# Why was my edit rejected when it improved the quality of the answer

Tags: discussion, support, edits, suggested-edits

So I was looking up how to do something and came across an answer which I needed here:

https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/9198333

Great.. But the answer was incomplete and I had to do further googling to complete the answer.

To be helpfull to people in the future I added the further information I found to the answer to complete it and make it more helpful to anyone returning in the future.

**But my edit was rejected.**

Reading the [Edit Page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/editing)

I was looking  the following reasons:

> **When should I edit posts?**
>
> - Any time you see a post that needs improvement and are inclined to  suggest an edit
> - Edits are expected to be substantial and to leave the post better than  you found it. Common reasons for edits include:
> - To include additional information only found in comments, so all of the information relevant to the post is contained in one place

Am I misunderstanding when edits should be used and what should I have done instead?

It felt stupid to leave a comment and then incorporate that into the answer

This is especially relevant as I am coming up to 2000 rep and the ability to edit un-moderated and don't want to be editing incorrectly

Comment: you have now edit privilege so it wont happen with you any more :)

Comment: Haha so I do.. I may go and make the edit again as I feel quite strongly that it will help others in the future. I would still like to understand why it was rejected initially though

Comment: though it will work

Comment: Looks like you were rejected by people who misread your edit as "Where is the namespace?" and then stopped thinking. Personally great edit, its exactly the type of thing that I think helps this site. So often a little clarification like that can make all the difference.

Comment: The same information already listed in the question *Where "s" is of course the System namespace.*, so your edit is not something new/improving. May be leave a comment instead?

Comment: If you want to add to an answer, I would suggest asking OP to the answer if he can do the edit, especially if it an accepted answer.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

When I glanced at that edit I assumed you were asking a new question:

> Where `s` is the namespace:
>
> ```
>       xmlns:s="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
> ```

And your comment is a little cryptic:

> added namespace declaration

It is always a gamble if you add stuff that looks like code and gets reviewed by either strict, robo or sheep<sup>1</sup> reviewers. The reviewers felt it was better left as a comment ( I don't think they expect your edit to qualify as a new answer).

I'm not a mind-reader but maybe this edit would have made it:

> Notice that the `s` namespace prefix should be defined as
>
> ```
> xmlns:s="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
> ```
>
> at the top of the document

And as a comment

> Added explicit statement where the namespace prefix is coming from. Doing that wrong and this answer will not work

But again, no guarantees. You can always leave your edit as a comment so either the OP can edit it in or a 2K-er (which you are now) will add it for you, by passing the unpredictability of the suggested-edits review queue.

<sup>1. term coined by [Gimby](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/302806/why-was-my-edit-rejected-when-it-improved-the-quality-of-the-answer/302809?noredirect=1#comment235472_302809)</sup>

Comment: _"gets reviewed by either strict or robo-viewers"_ - it was rejected by a reviewer who approved 1034 edit suggestions and rejected 5 edit suggestions... :P

Comment: I think that proves unpredictability ;)

Comment: its probably actually sheep-reviewing. When one or more people have already picked the "attempt to answer" option (which you can see as the site puts a number counter behind the option) its only too tempting to follow the herd.

Comment: @Gimby - Reviewers come in flocks, not herds.

Comment: @Jeeped I thought they were murders

Comment: "Radical change"s like this are discouraged in edits under 2k. They're ok, but the review queue isn't the best for determining if they're valid and they get frequently rejected.

Comment: I disagree that they saw it as a new question. Their rejection reason was "*This edit was intended to address the author of the post. It should have been written as a comment.*"

Answer (score 10):

It's very likely it's because in the question the OP question states:

> Where "s" is of course the System namespace.

This makes adding the comment simply seem like repeating what was already said in the question, hence being noise to the OP. Along with that it would make more sense to add that as an edit to the question itself:

> Where "s" is of course the System namespace:
>
> ```
>  xmlns:s="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
> ```

Otherwise you would add that exact same information other answers using `s`. Since the OP is defining `s` in the first place.

Comment: In fact it's very _unlikely_ that the reviewers bothered to read the question. Though I agree that there's not a lot of use in this edit.