# Should there be a section on the Help\Editing page about Edit Comments?

Tags: discussion, support, edits, comment-edits

Earlier today I asked this question:

[Why was my edit rejected when it improved the quality of the answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/302806/why-was-my-edit-rejected-when-it-improved-the-quality-of-the-answer)

the answer to the question essentially said that due to people reviewing vast numbers of edits the edit comment needs to be very clear to help the reviewer understand the change.

I was wondering whether it would be a good idea to include in the [Editing Help](https://stackoverflow.com/help/editing) section a part about a good edit comment?

Comment: That would be one part but you would also need guidance for the reviewers to tell them to check the comment if the edit is unclear and if that also doesn't work that they should visit the post to check why the edit was made. (or skip when in doubt)