# Should I edit an answer if it is incomplete?

Tags: discussion, support, edits, editing-help

Long story short: I [asked a question and got an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32078184/).
The answer itself isn't wrong and it guided me in the right direction, but for any future visitor this will not work, as an essential part is missing<sup>1</sup>. The answer is correct, but not complete.
I already wrote a comment under the answer, but...

... after reading [Why was my edit rejected when it improved the quality of the answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/302806/) I now wonder if I should edit the answer to be a full, working solution?

Another possibility is, of course, to write my own answer, but somehow this doesn't feel right in this particular case.

<sup>1</sup> When I just did what was written in the answer I got a compile-time Exception

Comment: You are above 2K, your edits don't go into the queue, but in cases like this make sure to clarify why you edit so much, leave a comment as well for the OP.

Comment: @rene I know my edits don't go into the queue I could just do it. I just want to know if the behaviour of editing "incomplete", but basically working answers is appropriate. Or if it's even better to write another answer incorporating the original answer.

Comment: "Another possibility is, of course, to write my own answer, but somehow this doesn't feel right in this particular case" I think its worth elaborating on that. Why not in this case?

Comment: @Gimby IMO the answer I would write builds completely upon his answer with only a little addition from me that has an huge impact. So I was tempted to just edit his answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It really depends on what and how much needs to be changed. It is important to answer the following question for your self:

> Will future visitors of my question be able to solve their similar problem with this answer.

You have a lot of context that let you fully grasp the issue and understand how the few lines in the answer puts you, in your context, on the right track. Visitors probably don't have that context. For the question and the answer to be of quality/value we should aim for clarity.

Depending on the size of the salvage operation:

- leave a comment and ask for an edit to include information that was overlooked/needs clarification
- edit the answer to add just that amount of context/fix that might be missed/overlooked by users (this includes a typo)
- <s>edit the answer to add your fully working solution, clearly separated from the content the answerer provided</s>(only if already CW)
- add a new answer with your full working solution including the few bits form the earlier answer, attribute to the answer that helped you
- add a new answer that is more a full-copy of the other answers and add a few bits of your own, but make it Community-Wiki before posting.

In the cases were you edit or add your own answer always leave a message for the answerer to indicate that you re-used the answer to turn it into a fully working solution. That might trigger the user to update their post or to review your solution and add valuable tips to it.

If you are below 2K be extremely cautious when suggesting edits to existing answers. Those edits go to be reviewed by at least 3 reviewers who, generally speaking, don't spend much time on the task. Try the comment option first. If you suggest an edit take your time to **ALSO** add a clear and precise explanation why the edit is needed, how it improves the value of the answer.

I would always try to get the user so far to add the stuff that is missing. For your particular example I'm not an SME that can judge if a rigorous edit of that answer is needed.

Comment: Your third point, editing the answer, is not an appropriate solution here.

Comment: Oh, and why is that @Servy?

Comment: Why is it not appropriate to edit someone's answer to add in your solution to theirs?  Because that's not what edits are for.  Edits are there to improve the presentation of the author's own content, not to add in your own, unless the post is already a CW post.

Comment: I wouldn't handle it that black-and-white but I don't care if that point is dropped....

Comment: Thanks for this thorough explanation! I will write a comment asking for an edit first and if nothing happens I will add my own answer attributing the other answer.