# Why was my clarification of the answerer's code rejected?

Tags: discussion, support, rejected-edits

[I proposed an edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/14423494) clarifying why the code in the answer worked. I also added a note about an edge case that would cause the answer to fail, which seems to me to be adding valuable information to the post, not fundamentally changing its intent.

This rejection was particularly frustrating because posts without explanation (i.e. that are *just* code) often aren't that helpful unless you happen to have the exact same problem in the exact same situation, or you know enough to figure it out yourself - both of which are frequently not the case.

So, why was this edit rejected? Did I do something wrong (I spend relatively little time on SO compared to other SE sites with different norms), or was I just unlucky and got a robo-reviewer or a [sheep](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/302806/why-was-my-edit-rejected-when-it-improved-the-quality-of-the-answer/302809?noredirect=1#comment235472_302809) reviewer or something?

Comment: Did you try asking any of the reviewers directly?

Comment: @Daedalus no, it didn't occur to me. I don't even know how I'd go about doing that.

Comment: You may be able to find them in chat, and while you'd also be able to ping them on any of their posts, I wouldn't advise that.

Comment: @Daedalus indeed :P
chat is an excellent idea, thanks.

Comment: That seems like a case of putting words in the author's mouth. The author did not say anything to the effect that you wrote. This means that it is down to technical accuracy. As reviewers in the edit queues are supposed to be making decisions based on technical accuracy, they can not be expected to verify the accuracy of your included explanation. Hence, they rejected it. That would have been a good example of a situation where you should have just posted your own answer.

Comment: Or more simply put: *"This edit was intended to address the author of the post and makes no sense as an edit. It should have been written as a comment or an answer."*

Comment: @TinyGiant the help center explicitly states that this kind of edits are encouraged.

Comment: I'm just curious if the rejections were made by subject matter experts able to discern whether the exposition conflicted with the posted code or if they merely reacted to a big green edit...

Comment: Hmm. honestly I probably would have approved the edit. The existing answer was a "Code only answer" and the detail you provided improved it in my opinion. Then again, I'm not a subject matter expert, so it's more likely I would have skipped it ;-)

Comment: @AndyG that's the attitude we should promote on reviewers!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When should I make edits to code?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260245/when-should-i-make-edits-to-code)

Comment: @gnat This is not an edit to code.

Comment: @duplode per my reading it qualifies as such by suggesting coding in a way that wasn't implied by original answerer, "the above won't work quite right if etc"

Comment: @gnat That (i.e. the second additional paragraph) is indeed a complicating factor for analysing this situation, but I'd say it is not enough to make that question a duplicate (even though it is certainly relevant).

Comment: In a situation such as this you might have submitted this as your own answer, perhaps marked as community wiki, with "To add to XYZ's already-excellent answer..." at the front.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

I am one of the reviewers who rejected the edit. I think @Tiny Giant said it best: you're putting words into the author's mouth.

To your credit, your edit is much better than the edits of most people who try to enhance answers by others. However, it is a very large addition to a highly upvoted and accepted answer.

In this case, it would be better to write it as your own answer. Then when people respond to the things you write, it will go to you.
If you were the OP, you would not want to be called out on things you didn't say; and conversely, you should not need praise for things you didn't say.

There is one other option, if you feel that it is better to keep this explanation with the original answer. That is to discuss it with the OP. If the OP agrees that the edit fits their own words (in comments or chat), you could re-submit, and link to that agreement in the Edit Summary.
If you're lucky, the OP may even be online themselves at the time of reviewing; the OP has a binding vote for edits, and the edit can then go through straight away.

Comment: In cases like your last option, I usually make a gist of my revision and link to it in a comment under the post, telling the user that they can do what they want with it

Comment: This edit should have been approved. I applied the edit. Next time, unless you are *very sure* that it's a edit that "fail to improve the post or that make it worse", **do not reject it.**

Comment: @canon I use skip more than any other button. In fact, I [proposed a WinterBash hat](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/270418/skippy-hat-use-winterbash-to-encourage-skip) last year to encourage it. (Fractional Radix is my account for playing with the API safely).

Comment: @Braiam I disagree. Unless you are very sure that an edit improves the post, do not approve it. If you are unsure, skip. If you are sure that it is a bad edit, reject.

Comment: @Alex how are you disagreeing with me? You are basically saying the same I did...

Comment: @Braiam I interpreted your wording with the use of bold font, as saying that the proof or burden regarding the quality of the edits is on those who reject. As if approvals are the norm, unless you are very sure that it is a bad edit.

Comment: @Alex if anything my position is: you aren't able to do an informed review, *skip*. I'm able to do an informed review of this edit, that's why I apply it. If anything, my quip was directed to the obnoxious trend of rejecting *anything* that adds or remove anything from a post, without taking into account the technical accuracy of the edit (basically, what Docs.SO reviewers should have be doing)

Comment: Oh, btw, this discussion is moot. The author was seen ~30 mins ago, didn't rolled back my edit.

Comment: @Braiam Ok, I agree with you that you should **skip** a review if you are not able to make an informed decision. Your phrasing in your comment above falsely made me think that you were saying "approve unless other indications".

Comment: @Alex I know my wording was sub-optimal, but I'm tired of seeing valid edits that for the informed improves the post getting rejected.

Comment: I rarely rollback edits made to my answers unless they are inaccurate or irrelevant. The most recent edit looks fine to me. This is a community driven site after all, that's kind of the point.

Comment: This is a much better plan than the borderline vandalism of almost rewriting somebody's (old, highly voted) post.

Comment: @Braiam Regardless of how the community ultimately votes on this edit, making the edit yourself and completely disregarding any kind of community discussion was absolutely wrong. It is an abuse of your ability to edit posts. Especially given that, by the votes on these answers, your viewpoint is in the minority. Try to respect that not everyone is going to agree with your view, and let the process play out on meta.

Comment: @ssube While there is reasonable disagreement on whether the edit went too far, adding correct explanatory notes to code-only answers is not "borderline vandalism" -- it is nowhere near that. (Tangentially relevant: note that Sean Bright in the comment just above is the original author of the answer in question.)

Comment: @ChrisHayes how is this abuse? The go to recommendation in this cases is for the editor to wait till they have 2k so they can bypass /review. If I had found this answer before I would have done the same: *edit to improve the answer*, since it's a mandate of SO. BTW, read Sean's comment too https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338986/why-was-my-clarification-of-the-answerers-code-rejected/338994?noredirect=1#comment418402_338994

Comment: @ChrisHayes funny that you claim I'm abusing my edit privileges yet you use WTFPL? Whatever happened to CC-by-sa and the provisions that anyone is able to edit others post, which was kinda the point.

Comment: @Braiam it's abuse because the editor asked and the community agreed, by upvoting this answer instead of yours, that the edit was inappropriate. You single-handedly applied it after that, knowing that most of the feedback disagreed with you and after seeing your answer downvoted.

Comment: @Braiam It was brought to meta for discussion, not so that you could see it and unilaterally impose your viewpoint on the post. If the author likes the edit, they can put it back in place themselves. It's not your place to completely circumvent the debate and decide "I'm right, forget what the community says about it".

Comment: @duplode I agree that adding correct content *can* be ok, but adding it after others have already rejected the edit and it's been brought to meta and again rejected is *not ok*.

Comment: @canon my point exactly, everyone jumps to "protect the author" but nobody seems to wait for the author to express its opinion.

Comment: @Braiam I will weight in also to express that passing over everybody here and applying it yourself is **not** ok. The point of meta is to achieve consensus, then act. You basically said "F*** you" to everyone and single handedly played moderator, neither did you wait for the author to "express their opinion". you just applied the edit.

Comment: @canon which is no reason to do that. yes, in this case the author agrees, does that really mean that everyone should go and add *that much* content to posts because they feel like it, on the odd chance that "bah whatever, op will probably approve and if not, too bad"?

Comment: @canon my point is not that it was a bad edit, but that it was a bad suggested edit. It should have been discussed first. There is no way to filter based on tags in the suggested edits queue because edits in that queue should generally be reviewable by anyone. Whether it had been discussed with the author, on meta, or in chat, it should have been discussed

Comment: It should either have been discussed with the author beforehand, or posted as a separate answer. This time it went well because the original editor agreed (afterward). But what if it had contained a subtle but dangerous flaw? Posting as a separate answer allows the community to judge it separately.

Comment: But community has demonstrated that they don't know and aren't even willing to investigate whenever or not a edit has technical merits on its own. Most reject anything that the author hasn't put themselves out of a misguided fear that *it may be wrong*, which is absurd and at odds with SE mandate: If you see something that needs improvement, **click edit!**

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier I have the technical authority to do such edits. That's what I'm supposed to do. Last time I checked SE prefers technically correctness over everything else, author itself has approved. There isn't a need for "consensus" to make such edits.

Comment: If anything, the comments here should make you reconsider your view @Braiam. Please stop bringing back that the author has approved, it happened **after** you edited.... I can't help but feel you act and speak as if you know everything better than everyone else. Could you please take a step back here? **People disagree with you**. Are you just playing jungle's law? inb4 you say that people are wrong and you know better. circular logic ftw.

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier Why can't you reconsider yours? I had the technical expertise to apply the edit. Full stop. That's what should matter. If I have the technical expertise to do a technical edit, are you against that? BTW, my only law is what SE mandates: **If you see something that needs improvement, click edit!**

Comment: @Braiam when an edit has *already been rejected* by the community **more than once**, you have no right or reason to apply it. One OP agreeing with one edit is not carte blanche to continue abusing the edit system and ignoring the input of everyone on meta.

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier you are free to edit any of my answer, if you have the technical expertise to improve them (I will obviously review them). That's what my point is about. A community without experts is a community that doesn't have *place* on SO.

Comment: @ssube what? I have edited the answer [exactly one time](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/532538/revisions), so stop misguiding people. **My edit** as it's has been approved.

Comment: @Braiam I reconsider my views very often. And actually, you have no idea what my view is. I would probably have skipped that edit. What I am speaking of is your single-handed actions, and after reconsidering all of this, taking into account the other comment, I stand firm on my view. Consensus is not something that you should just reject because you think you have authority on a subject. I mean, you are literally saying that community is wrong, and that you are right. Seriously, stop right there.

Comment: @canon Actually, the community presently is trying to get said subject expert to post that much original content as a new answer, so that they can get credit for it *and* put the relevant content online, as far as I understand this. As for your claim, I'll do as if you're not overlooking the countless other occasions where community also prevents newcomers to just add their new favorite way of verifying wether a variable is null or not in the last javascript duplicate about that ;). tbh I have no strong view however, maybe the trade off is not that good.

Comment: @canon: yours was not a substantial change. That's a 1 character edit. Not to worry about. My edit changed 80% or more. Look at it in this view: http://stackoverflow.com/posts/1091953/revisions

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier I mostly agree with you on the procedural point, but on the other hand, we're used to the "meta effect" where meta folks interfere with any and every post that is brought up (voting, closing, deleting). This imposition of the disputed edit could be seen as a natural extension of that and so not such a big deal. Btw, canon has spun this issue off into a more general meta post: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/339101/

Comment: @Frank It's gotten to the point where I kinda consider meta to be *part* of this ongoing "moderating and reviewing the site activity". I sometimes start to believe meta is actually here to deal with the edge cases, such as this one, and that we should leave the system deal with all the crap going on, and use our active attention to consider valid cases.

Comment: accepting this answer as it's very obviously the consensus of the community. that being said I think that while this is the most reasonable answer _within the existing review system_, I think this is in general harmful for SE and we should probably fix that by improving Review.

Comment: @strugee Shog says otherwise: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/339523/792066, btw, there's no "consensus" here, just two forces in opposition when they've never meant to oppose each other (my answer for example, has score 29/-39, which obviously is not consensus).

Comment: @Braiam You're interpreting Shog9's answer different than I do. I do agree, however, that there is no consensus; just a majority position. And it's fine if an asker marks the minority position answer as Accepted, if that is the one they agree with.

Comment: If you read @strugee comment, he says "this is in general harmful for SE", he doesn't agree that that's the best, just that unless you fix /review it seems to be the "path of lest resistance"

Comment: @Braiam fair enough. still makes sense to accept this as the answer though - I think it's the closest to "consensus" we're going to get (and more generally, it _does_ answer my question, even if I disagree with the premise)

Answer (score -9):

> Why can people edit my posts? How does editing work?
>
> All contributions are **licensed under Creative Commons**, and this site is collaboratively edited, like Wikipedia. **If you see something that needs improvement, click edit!**

I still have problem warping my head around this kind of rejection.

> Edits are expected to be substantial and to leave the post better than you found it. Common reasons for edits include:
>
> - To fix grammar and spelling mistakes
> - **To clarify the meaning of the post** (without changing that meaning)
> - **To include additional information only found in comments**, so all of the information relevant to the post is contained in one place
> - To correct minor mistakes or add updates as the post ages
> - To add related resources or hyperlinks

You fulfilled at least two common reasons to edit someone post, there's nothing on the help center that says you cannot do this kind of edits. *Nothing*. This is a wiki! If we cannot edit content to improve it, what makes us any different from what SO was meant to replace?

> That seems like a case of putting words in the author's mouth

It wasn't putting words into the author mouth. The author already spoke, but what he said it's not easily understandable. What the edit made was translating what the author said in code into plain english.

> That would have been a good example of a situation where you should have just posted your own answer.

So, the answer would be "repeat what it already said elsewhere"? That seems not optimal for two reasons:

1. The author can claim that content is copied, heck I would downvote such answers that regurgitate someone code, most of what rejected your edit would do the same *too*.
2. It adds unnecessary overhead. If something change on emacs-lisp, we now have to modify **two** answers instead of one, which goes against the principle of canonical answers.
3. Code only answers are not "good quality", and you improved that to make it "good quality".

Your edit was bogus rejected, and if anything, author should be the one to decide whenever you were putting words on his mouth or improving his answer.

Comment: In your view, is the fact that the editor was below 2k, and so the edit had to go through review, relevant to this discussion? (Quoting Tiny Giant's comment on that issue: "The author did not say anything to the effect that you wrote. This means that it is down to technical accuracy. As reviewers in the edit queues are [not] supposed to be making decisions based on technical accuracy, they can not be expected to verify the accuracy of your included explanation.")

Comment: @duplode as reviewer I abstain of reviewing anything I can't do an informed decision about. That was why this feature request was rejected http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/283479/792066

Comment: In such cases, this stance frames the discussion in terms of abstaining (and leaving the edit in suspension until the author or tag expert visitors look at it) versus rejecting. Tangentially, I wonder if the editor would (or,at least, should) have had better luck if the edit summary also said something to the effect of "moving extra information from comments to answer".

Comment: @duplode I highly doubt it would make the result any different, remember that reviewers [tend to have tunnel vision](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/315855/792066), and reject these edits in a knee jerk reaction. I think we should change how reviewers fundamentally review edits, and that start by post like mine that raise awareness.

Comment: While I have my doubts about the limits of applicability of "This is a Wiki" as a principle for justifying edits (e.g. Stack Overflow and Wikipedia handle authorship in quite different ways), I believe your argument is very relevant this specific situation.

Comment: We're not supposed to be required to do mental gymnastics in order to determine the validity of the suggested edit. If the edit comment had stated it was including information from the comments, I would be saying something different. But as it stands, the edit comment lends no credibility to the edit.

Comment: @TinyGiant "We're not supposed to be required to do mental gymnastics in order to determine the validity of the suggested edit." [citation needed] Shog in his own post states that if you aren't willing to do due diligence to do a informed *review* you are supposed to allow others to do it. Review implies *reviewing*. If you aren't going to do serious reviewing, allow others to do it.

Comment: It is th editors job to make a case for their edit by utilizing the edit comment. They did not do that. Based on the context of the edit comment, and what is visible on the review screen, i see no reason to approve the edit. Again, if the editor had used the edit comment to explain their actions, i would be saying something different. By mental gymnastics i mean we shouldnt have to navigate to the post and try to guess why the edit was suggested.

Comment: @TinyGiant humor me for a second and write a revision comment that would be valid? You know what, I will do mine: **Add explanation and a note about a case where this might fail**.

Comment: Include explanation and case where this may fail from author in comments

Comment: @TinyGiant that's not fair: first you claim that "The author did not say anything to the effect that you wrote", when I objected that you changed to "We're not supposed to be required to do mental gymnastics in order to determine the validity of the suggested edit", which Shog throughly disagree with, then you switched to "t is th editors job to make a case for their edit by utilizing the edit comment", tell me, are you ever going to get convinced that this edit should be approved? If you aren't willing to change your views, that's not a constructive discussion, isn't it?

Comment: Sorry, I was on my phone when commenting on this answer and had inferred based on the comments here that there was information contained in the comments which was being moved into the answer. Upon further review, there is no such information. This edit is made up purely of the author's interpretation of the code. It is not up to suggested edit reviewers to verify the accuracy of that interpretation. The editor could have brought it to the author, brought it up in chat with subject matter experts, brought it up on meta, or any number of other things.

Comment: @TinyGiant "This edit is made up purely of the author's interpretation of the code." -- In your view, would it have made any difference if the editor had added references to the Emacs documentation in support of the edit? (I suppose you wouldn't find it enough for accepting the answer, given the concerns about accuracy verification that you mention, but I wonder what would you think about the reviewers abstaining in deference to the answer author and tag experts in such a case.)

Comment: But note that I did not change my position on the suggested edit. It does put words in the authors mouth, and as said in my first comment on the question here reviewers in the suggested edit queue are not supposed to be making decisions based on technical accuracy, but rather the maintenance of the intent of the post and respect to the author. This is also what I meant by mental gymnastics. The Q&A you referenced seems to be only about the close vote review queue, not suggested edits.

Comment: @duplode it definitely would have given me more to consider when reviewing the edit. Whether or not it would change my position would depend on the references and explanation.

Comment: @TinyGiant why not just hitting skip? I mean, you aren't forced to review every item is presented to you, and practically speaking is a waste of time that you dedicate more than 3 minutes mulling over what to do with an edit. Isn't on everyone best interest that on those cases, you simply skip it and look for something that you are able to form an informed opinion about, [like this edit](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/14318961).

Comment: @Braiam Why can't people just skip when they don't know what they're looking at?

Comment: @canon I'm not sure myself. I hit the skip whenever I have to think too much about what I'm seeing, dunno what would be the motivations of others?

Comment: @Braiam [relevant](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/339101/the-community-vs-the-domain-expert/339127#339127)