# What if an suggested edit improves everything about a post except it does one bad thing?

Tags: discussion, review-queues, edits, suggested-edits

What should I do when I am reviewing an edit and the editor fixes a LOT of things in a post (i.e. put blocks of code in code blocks, puts quotes in blockquotes, and fixes a lot of grammar and adds appropriate tags) but then does something like change a small section of code or just adds a small section of text that conflicts with the OP's intent?

Should I "Improve Edit" and undo the bad bits or should I "Reject and Edit" and then make all the improvements myself? I'm thinking that "Improve Edit" will be a lot easier since there is only a small part that I will have to revert. But this will send a message to the editor that these kinds of edits are ok. On the other hand, an overwhelming majority of the edit is very positive. It clarifies the rest of the post immensely. I wouldn't want to dismiss the editor's work. So what should I do?

Comment: One common "bad thing" that suggested edits do is use `code formatting` to add `emphasis` to certain `words`, or in lieu of quotation marks, like your question does here. Code formatting is intended to be used *exclusively* for code, things like identifiers, keywords, etc. If you want to quote bits of text, use quotation marks. If you want to add emphasis, use bold and/or italics.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Here's how I look at it:

- If it'd take you longer to fix everything yourself than it would to just fix the bits that the edit breaks, Improve.
- If it'd take you less time to just make all of the necessary changes than it would to unbork the suggested edit, Reject and Edit.

And don't turn yourself into a mindless automaton by thinking that all code edits are bad. Tons of folks make useful code edits; heck, I've had kind souls fix code in my posts and it'd be a real shame if someone had rejected them without knowing what they were doing.

Skip, as usual, is always a good option if you're unsure.

Comment: I thought "accept" and "reject" had value beyond convenience (like "please don't make such changes in future")... Is it no longer the case?

Comment: Sure, @Alexei. But don't put the cart before the horse. If someone's producing mostly-good, comprehensive edits, you probably *do* want 'em to do more. If someone's producing edits that take more work to fix than to discard, you probably want 'em to do less.

Comment: *"Tons of folks make useful code edits; heck, I've had kind souls fix code in my posts and it'd be a real shame if someone had rejected them without knowing what they were doing."* This times 100. The Meta guidance recently seems to have turned in the direction of "never edit code", which as far as I'm concerned is horribly misguided. Sure, if you don't know what you're doing, you shouldn't edit code. But you also shouldn't edit anything else. And if you aren't sure, you shouldn't be approving. But that's why God created the "Skip" button.

Comment: @CodyGray The problem with that advice is the bit "if you don't know what you're doing". Lots of people lack the introspection (or humility) to know when they don't know what they're doing (witness 90% of Documentation)...

Comment: Which is why we have reviewers, @Mike. Which is exactly what goes wrong with Documentation, since there are virtually no qualifications for being a reviewer.

Comment: And before someone comments about that *reviewers also "don't know what they're doing"* to @CodyGray , just skip reading the next lines.

Answer (score 5):

You should absolutely be rejecting the edit when someone is making an inappropriate change like that.  Like you said, if you approve the edit, you send the signal that the change is okay.

As far as making it easy to keep the content that was appropriately changed, just copy the markup into the reject and edit page, and then change it as needed, rather than taking the time to re-apply the edits yourself.

Comment: "You should absolutely be rejecting the edit when someone is making an inappropriate change like that. " "that" means what exactly? "put blocks of code in code blocks" seems like something we should encourage, no? "puts quotes in blockquotes" this bothers me to no end, I would like editors to fix these. "fixes a lot of grammar and adds appropriate tags" I'm sure this is a good thing.

Comment: @Braiam I think Servy meant the one bad thing I mentioned in my question.

Comment: @KodosJohnson I think that my comment was directed to how it represented that we should reject all the good things that we want to encourage, for a insignificant problem that most would be able to fix ourselves.

Comment: *"if you approve the edit, you send the signal that the change is okay"* At the same time, if you reject the edit, you send the signal that the positive changes were not okay. There's a balance to be had, and it depends on whether the positive changes outweigh the negative ones. If an edit is on the tipping point for you, skip.

Comment: @4castle Not when you're keeping those changes that are helpful.

Comment: So in other words, you're saying we should Improve Edit when people under-edit, and we should Reject and Edit when people over-edit? I would prefer that people get rewarded for making substantial improvements in both situations.

Comment: @4castle You would prefer rewarding people for making actively harmful changes that would cause significant problems if not caught, encouraging them to continue performing those harmful behaviors, and not only not knowing that they're harmful, but *thinking that they're helpful* based on the feedback they're being given, resulting in them continuing to make more and more of those harmful edits, either resulting in later rejections, or worse, them getting through review and being applied to actual posts?

Comment: @Servy If the edit was actively making harmful changes changes that would cause significant problems, then that would outweigh the good in their edit. I would reject it. But when people are making edits that are significant improvements, I would approve it. They would see the things that I removed from the edit, and I could leave a comment depending on the situation.

Answer (score 4):

> What if an suggested edit improves everything about a post except it does one bad thing?

So, a single bad thing that can take you no time to fix... I think that the answer is pretty straightforward. Improve the edit. The edit do improves the quality of the post, it just messed up in a single thing (could be unintentional?), it's less work for you to fix that single thing. BTW, did someone know that while on review you can copy the pre-edit markdown in the "side-by-side markdown"?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130633/discussion-on-answer-by-braiam-what-if-an-suggested-edit-improves-everything-abo).

Answer (score 2):

If you approve-and-edit to fix the one thing they made worse, leave a comment if it was something important.  You can `@username` notify people who have made edits to a post you're commenting on.

Let them know that while their edit was overall useful, they should be more careful with their edits in future to avoid breakage that a less careful review might have let slip through.

If it was an honest mistake, that's fine.  If it was bad judgement or lack of testing (for code changes) before putting something into someone else's answer, then that's something they need to learn.